# The Preview Doesn't Displayed At The Launching (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, xml, sdk, preview

I started learning the Android SDK and I have a problem.
I launched the studio and the android screen didn't show up (YES, I know where the preview tool bar and how to switch).
Quote:

"Rendering Problems The following classes could not be found:
- android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
 Tip: Try to build the project."

*Sometimes there is another rendering problem and this is showed :
"Rendering Problems The following classes could not be instantiated: - android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)"

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure its the "appcompat_v7", which is automatically generated in eclipse when setting up an android project. It imports unnecessary features and causes a bunch of build errors.

1. Delete "appcompat_v7" folder
2. - go to your MainActivity
   - Delete the import "android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity";
   - change "MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity" to  "MainActivity extends Activity"
3. - add import android.app.Activity;
   - add import android.os.Bundle;
   - add import android.view.Menu;
   - add import android.view.MenuItem;
4. go to res folder and then go to your values folder...delete styles.xml
5. delete values-v11 folder
6. delete values-v14 folder
7. go to menu folder, and click on main.xml...go to "item" tag and delete app:showAsAction="never"
8. go to AndroidManifest.xml...go to "application" tag...delete  android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
9. go to project at the top...clean and build...you should have no more errors.

Comment: Hey Andrew,
First of all , thank you !
second, I failed founding 'project' at paraghraph 9. can you explain it better please?
i'm  repeat i'm beginner

Comment: no problem : let me know if you have any more problems

Comment: No more problems with it, just with HAXM.. :\
But i asked about just now.